# Uniswap "Approve" was completed, yet I still got charged the fee and have to approve again?

Tags: uniswap

I tried swapping GHOST for ETH on uniswap. First I had to approve the tokens before swapping, there was a message that it only has to be approved once.

It took a full day but today I checked on Etherscan, and the transaction was approved.

https://etherscan.io/address/0x02e566690Cb197A6742582F06E39A7c7234a9aF8

So I logged into Uniswap with Metamask, and I clicked on "Swap" but nothing happened. Then I checked my Metamask and it had a transaction waiting to be approved, I clicked on it, but now it seems that this is another "approve" transaction, no actual swap. When I try to swap my GHOST now, it doesnt work, there is the approve button once again.

So I already paid once and apparently another approve is going on right now, without any actual swap happening.

Weird thing is, when I check the token on Etherscan, it shows that people have been able to swap, but why does it not work for me? What am I missing here?

Link to the Token:
https://etherscan.io/token/0x4c327471C44B2dacD6E90525f9D629bd2e4f662C

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

The first approve [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1940e02021dbe42b652bac82b728d313b8d9a47b72e78abe23babd0e79fe8cba) was for the [uniswap v2 router](https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D).

The second approve [transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x099071c5f75866b06aeb1ceadb4f82e6cb684f73d3534a84941a595d1861820f) is for the [metamask router](https://etherscan.io/address/0x881d40237659c251811cec9c364ef91dc08d300c#code). As of 2021-11-05 03:53 it is still pending.